# Odoo14: Module cannot be install - Cancel Install

Tags: python, xml, events, python-3.6, odoo-14

I am using Odoo 14 and couldn't install when try installing a custom module for events. I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Under Apps, on my module there is a button showed called 'Cancel Install'. I want to create a new module called 'events'. I have attached below the codes from model.py and views.xml. Please do guide me as I'm new to Python and Odoo 14.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import base64
from werkzeug.urls import url_encode

from odoo import models, fields, api
from datetime import datetime
from odoo.modules.module import get_module_resource


class Events(models.Model):
    _name = 'test-events'
    _description = 'test-events'
    _order = 'name'

    name = fields.Char(string="Event Name", size=200, store=True, readonly=False)
    description = fields.Text(string="Description")
    event_type = fields.Integer(string="Event Type", required=True)
    status = fields.Integer(string="Status", required=True)
    start_at = fields.Datetime.to_string(datetime.datetime.now(string="Start at", help='Event Start Date & Time', required=True))
    end_at = fields.Datetime.to_string(datetime.datetime.now(string="End at", help='Event End Date & Time', required=True))
    created_at = fields.Datetime.now(string="Created at", help='Event Create Date & Time', required=True)
    updated_at = fields.Datetime.to_string(datetime.datetime.now(string="Updated at", help='Event Update Date & Time', required=True))
    thumbnail_url = fields.Char(string="Thumbnail URL", size=500, help='Event Image URL', required=True)

    @api.model
    def _default_image(self):
        image_path = get_module_resource('events', 'img', 'default_image.png')
        return base64.b64encode(open(image_path, 'rb').read())

    image_1920 = fields.Image(default=_default_image)

 

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        """Method Override for allocate leaves to the employee."""
        if vals.get('id'):
            user = self.env['test-events'].browse(vals['id'])
            vals.update(self._sync_user(user, vals.get('image_1920') == self._default_image()))
            vals['name'] = vals.get('name', user.name)
        events = super(Events, self).create(vals)
        url = '/web#%s' % url_encode({
            'active_id': events.id,
            'active_model': 'test-events',
        })
        events_allocations = self.env['test-events']
        for events_allocation in events_allocations:
            events_dict = {
                'name': events_allocation.name,
                'description': events_allocation.description,
                'event_type': events_allocation.event_type,
                'status': events_allocation.status,
                'start_at': events_allocation.start_at,
                'end_at': events_allocation.end_at,
                'created_at': events_allocation.created_at,
                'updated_at': events_allocation.updated_at,
                'thumbnail_url': url,
            }
            new_allocation = self.env['test-events'].create(events_dict)
            new_allocation.sudo().action_approve()
        return events
```

Above is my model.py file. While below is my views.xml file.

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <!-- explicit list view definition -->

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="events.list">
      <field name="name">events list</field>
      <field name="model">test-events</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree>
          <field name="name"/>
          <field name="description"/>
          <field name="event_type"/>
          <field name="status"/>
          <field name="start_at"/>
          <field name="end_at"/>
          <field name="created_at"/>
          <field name="updated_at"/>
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>

    <record id="test_events_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">test-events.form</field>
            <field name="model">test-events</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Events" create="0" write="0" js_class="events_form">
                    <header/>
                    <sheet>
                        <field name="image_1920" widget='image' class="oe_avatar" options='{"zoom": true, "preview_image":"image_128"}'/>
                            <div class="oe_title">
                                <label for="name" class="oe_edit_only"/>
                                <h1>
                                    <field name="name" placeholder="Events's Name" required="True"/>
                                </h1>
                                <h2>
                                    <field name="description" placeholder="Event's Description" />
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                            <group>
                                <group>
                                    <field name="event_type"/>
                                    <field name="start_at"/>
                                    <field name="created_at"/>
                                </group>
                                <group>
                                    <field name="status"/>
                                    <field name="end_at"/>
                                    <field name="updated_at"/>
                                </group>
                            </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>


    <!-- actions opening views on models -->

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_event_view">
      <field name="name">Events</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
      <field name="res_model">test-events</field>
      <field name="view_mode">kanban,calendar,tree,form,pivot,graph</field>
    </record>
    <!-- server action to the one above -->

    <record model="ir.actions.server" id="events.action_server">
      <field name="name">events server</field>
      <field name="model_id" ref="model_events_events"/>
      <field name="state">code</field>
      <field name="code">
        action = {
          "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
          "view_mode": "kanban,calendar,tree,form,pivot,graph",
          "res_model": test-events,
        }
      </field>
    </record>


    <!-- Top menu item -->
    <!-- MAIN MENU -->
    <menuitem name="Events"
        id="events_main_menu"
        web_icon="event,static/description/icon.png"/>

    <!-- HEADER: EVENTS -->
    <menuitem name="Events"
        id="header_menu_events"
        parent="events_main_menu"/>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

Following with my *manifest*.py file. Please help me out. I'm really not sure where us my wrong.odoo

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "events",

    'summary': """
        Organize, publish, and manage on-site & online events """,

    'description': """
        An all-in-one event management platform, capable of handling events of any type or scale. Odoo 
        Events covers all aspects of an Event Planner's job from organize, publish, and manage events 
        like Conferences, Webinars, Meetings, Classes, Registrations, Charity, Exhibitions, and Festivals.
    """,

    'author': "My Company",
    'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

    # Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
    # Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_module_category_data.xml
    # for the full list
    'category': 'Marketing/Events',
    'version': '0.1',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base', 'base_setup', 'mail', 'portal', 'utm'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

Comment: I see you create new model test-events but you don't create access right for this model and I found you close 'security/ir.model.access.csv' in your minifest file.

Comment: Please try it by removing demo block from manifest as you don't have any demo file and add security file.

Comment: Please consider using the standard module creation way :  odoo-bin scaffold my_module ~/src/user/ as describred in https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/odoo_sh/getting_started/first_module.html

Comment: Thank you for your help guys [Aung Ko Ko Lin, Himanshu Sharma, sylvain] as now I'm able to install my module successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the standard way to create a custom module :

```
  odoo-bin scaffold events ~/src/user/
```

It will create the default access rules for your module and you can copy/paste your existing code in the standard directory (modules, controlles, views, data...)
More info (official documentation) : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/odoo_sh/getting_started/first_module.html